# Storing Text from two dimensional Array to Database Table

Tags: android, arrays, android-sqlite

I am working on an app which stores students Roll No and Names.I have managed to store the text of Edit-texts into a two dimensional `String array Data[][]`(The reason i am using array is because every student have two edit texts one for roll number and one for name), the problem that i face is that when i pass the `Data[][]` to the method of entry it gives error.

Code of Array Passing to method.

```
OurDatabase entry = new OurDatabase(StudentEntery.this);
entry.createEntry(data);
```

Code of Create Entry Method.

```
public void createEntry(String[][] data) {
    ourDatabase=object.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ROLLNO, data[0][0].toString());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAMES,  data[0][1].toString());           
    ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    ourDatabase.close();
}
```

Comment: please provide logcat error message . which error did you get??

Comment: @mcd it gives nullpointerexception, it has some thing to do with the data in array , maybe it is not accessible , the method is in other class, is the passing of data[][] array done right or do i have to do it another way.

Comment: @MuhammadImran you need to provide more information including full logcat and maybe some more code if possible. Right now we can just guess . Are you sure that your array is initialized with values?